# Why am I unable to have my bot type into the credit card input section when it grabs the element through the website's html code?

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, automation

Long story short, I am trying to create the back end of a sneaker bot for the Kith website (https://kith.com/). I am using the selenium library and its webdriver in order to web scrape and capture the website's elements. Everything seems to be fine until I reach the credit card input section. Once I try and copy the xpath for the input boxes (cc number, cvv, etc) it returns an error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: 
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"'//*[@id="number"]"}
```

Is there perhaps a feature within Html that disables you from grabbing and typing into this input box using the bot, or am I doing something wrong? If this is a legitimate feature, any bypass options?

My code to grab the input boxes are:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="number"]').send_keys(keys['cc_number'])
#Name on Card
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id=name"]').send_keys(keys['name_on_card'])
#exp date
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="number"]').send_keys(keys['card_expiration_date'])
#security code
driver.find_element_by_id('//*[@id="number"]').send_keys(keys['card_cvv'])
```

This is the raw Html code for the CC # input box:

`<input autocomplete="cc-number" id="number" name="number" type="tel" aria-describedby="error-for-number tooltip-for-number" data-current-field="number" class="input-placeholder-color--lvl-22" placeholder="Card number" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; padding: 0.94em 0.8em; transition: padding 0.2s ease-out 0s;">`

and then this is what value is copied every time I use its XPATH code `//*[@id="number"]`

Comment: I didn't create an account to verify, but usually, e-commerce websites will protect payment information fields. Some times they may be inside a `<iframe>` or be generated by javascript on the fly. Try to inspect the page and check for those things. Or post the inspected HTML in your question so we can take a look.

Comment: You've got three different elements that you're trying to find with `id=number`.  id's are supposed to be unique.

Comment: @JohnGordon every time I go and copy the xpath, that's the only value that is  copied `//*[@id="number"] `

Comment: always put code, data and error mesages in question, not in comment - it will be more readable.

Comment: when I check HTML in browser it has `id="cardNumber`, not `id="number"`. Similar other elements have different IDs then you shows. Maybe it shows different IDs for different cards.

Comment: it is in `<iframe>` so `Selenium` treads it as separted page and you have to use `driver.switch_to.frame()`